# Why is $ \text{Rank}(A^{215}) = 3 $?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

I have a question. Why is $ \text{Rank}(A^{215}) = 3 $, where
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 & 0 \\ 2 & 0 & 2 \end{bmatrix}?
$$
How can I even calculate this? I’m sure that there’s an easy way to do this. I thought that maybe I would just calculate $ \text{Rank}(A) $, which is $ 4 $, and it would be the same after putting it in reduced row echelon form. However, the correct answer is $ 3 $. Why please?

Comment: The matrix you give is 3 by 3; its rank can never be 4.

Comment: Is it a $3\times 3$ matrix?

Comment: Maybe you're confusing rank and determinant?

Comment: You can easily compute the diagonal elements of $A^n$ and show that it is invertible, hence has full rank.

Comment: @RobertIsrael  yes your are right.  i confused rank with determinant.

Comment: As you have already shown that $ \det(A) = 4 $, we can see that $ \det(A^{215}) = 4^{215} \neq 0 $. Therefore, $ A $ is invertible, which implies that it has full rank.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

The matrix $A$ is invertible if and only if $A^k$ is invertible for all $k\in\Bbb N$ if and only if $A$ is a full-rank matrix.

Comment: so if an N*N matrix is invertible , the rank is equal to the dimention of the matrix ? if so i just check if the determinant is not equal to zero - for the matrix without the exponent
and if so . the rank is the same as the rank of any exponent ?

Comment: Yes!${}{}{}{}{}$